# Executing TCL (expect script) using perl on windows

Tags: perl, tcl, expect

I'm running the tcl(which has expect script) using perl with,

```
system("C:/Tcl/bin/tclsh86 C:/Users/sysadmin/desktop/expect.tcl");
```

It's not executing the all commands in the script, but its working fine on ubuntu.
What command should i use to run this completely using perl on Windows?

Comment: Did you install TCL compiler in windows.?

Comment: Yeah, i've installed (tclsh86), its not showing any error, but the complete tcl(expect) script is not executing

Comment: how do you know it's not running all the commands? show us something.

Comment: Even I tried to run on windows cmd, its giving the same partial output of TCL(expect) script. What can i do for executing the complete script?

Comment: @glenn, In unix i can see the complete output, but if i try to run on windows, the complete thing is not coming as in unix.

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` near the top of your expect script and see what's in the debugging output

Comment: tried it just now...shows me the diagnostics for every line of the partial output and it comes out of the script after that

Answer (score 0):

On Unix Expect works using virtual terminals. By contrast, Expect on Windows uses the debugging subsystem. (There's *nothing* like virtual terminals on Windows.) This has the down-side that programs that are marked as being impossible to debug (i.e., some system programs, notably including `telnet.exe` though `ftp.exe` might also be on that list) cannot be automated by Expect at all. The OS just refuses to let Expect connect to the process.

Is this what is happening to you? I can't tell from the minimal information you've given, but it is by far the most common reason for problems with porting an Expect script between platforms (once you've taken into account mundane things like different paths and programs that just aren't there on all platforms).

The up-side is that both Tcl and Perl are quite capable of talking directly to anything that you'd use `telnet` or `ftp` to talk to (as both are entirely proficient at TCP/IP). In fact, both are probably better at doing it natively than anything you'd likely achieve through use of Expect.